# System for saving objects

Tags: java, processing

I want to create a system for saving objects. I'm using processing. Now I do it this way:

```java
void Save()
{  
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = "0";
  JSONObject js;
  JSONArray values = new JSONArray();

  switch(mode) {
  case 1:
    for (int i = 0; i<cir.size(); i++)
    {
      json = gson.toJson(cir.get(i));
      js = parseJSONObject(json);
      values.setJSONObject(i, js);
    }
    break;
  case 2:
    if (pendul)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i< pend.size(); i++)
      {
        json = gson.toJson(pend.get(i));
        js = parseJSONObject(json);
        values.setJSONObject(i, js);
      }
    } else 
    {
      for (int i = 0; i< doublePend.size(); i++)
      {
        json = gson.toJson(doublePend.get(i));
        js = parseJSONObject(json);
        values.setJSONObject(i, js);
      }
    }
    break;
  }
  
  save.saves(values);
}

class SaveGame
{
  Gson gson; 
  String json;
  JSONObject js;

  SaveGame()
  {
    gson = new Gson();
  }

  void saves(JSONArray obj)
  {
 
    boolean exist = true;
    if (obj != null)
    {
      File f;
      int i = -1;
      do
      {
        i++;
        f = dataFile("saves/save" + i + ".txt");     
        exist = f.isFile();
      }
      while (exist);
      println(f, " ",obj);
      saveJSONArray(obj, "saves/save" + i + ".txt");
    }  
  }
}
```

But something isn't working, and I have a lot of errors, and I don't know why:

```
SEVERE: An error occured while forwarding a Controller event, please check your code at Save
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.awt.Frame declares multiple JSON fields named state
```

Would someone be able to help me with this? The entire project is here: https://github.com/Rafhub69/Everythig

Comment: I'm not sure there is a way to see what's wrong just with the code you shared, but it's important that you learn how to use the error messages: Your error says `class java.awt.Frame declares multiple JSON fields named state` you should try to find this `Frame` instance and how you use it and try to find out how you end up with two fields `state` in there. My guess would be that you try to save several pendulum objects in the same json object and that gives you duplicated keys, but your code really lacks of context for us to be 100% sure.

Comment: I don't use any Frame instance, and I don't try to save several objects in the same istance, because I use JSONArray to do that.

Comment: Now my code look like this: https://pastebin.com/ZSLX1yRb, but I still have a problem. At this point, I don't know why, but in the resulting file, after everything is done, the last js call is repeated in place of all previous JSONs.